# How to get year and month separately from this string in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, date

I have this string format mm/yyyy-

`01/2010`

how do i get the month and year separately from it. I want it separately 01 and 2010 in a way i could compare them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
declare @d char(7);
declare @Month varchar(2);
declare @Year varchar(4);

set @d = '01/2010';

SET @Month = LEFT(@d, 2);
SET @Year = RIGHT(@d, 4);
```

Answer (score 3):

This should hook you up (assumes that @Date represents your date string):

```
DECLARE @SlashPos int;
SET @SlashPos = CHARINDEX('/', @Date);

Declare @Month varchar(2);
Declare @Year varchar(4);

SET @Month = SUBSTRING(@Date, 1, @SlashPos - 1);
Set @Year = SUBSTRING(@Date, @SlashPos + 1, LEN(@Date) - @SlashPos);
```

At this point, `@Month` and `@Year` will contain strings representing the month and year.

Comment: My pleasure.  Leniel's answer should also work if your months are all 2 digits long, and is a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

check out help for substring and charindex functions